# A basis that makes a matrix triangular.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form, generalized-eigenvector

Find a basis for $\mathbb C^3$ so that the following matrix is in triangular form:

\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}

What are the eigenvalues?

I found the eigenvalues to be $\lambda_1 = 1, \lambda_2 = \frac{1}{2}(-1 - i \sqrt{3} ), \lambda_3 = \frac{1}{2}(-1 + i \sqrt{3} ).$ And the eigenvectors to be $$\begin{pmatrix}1\\
1\\
1
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}\frac{ -(\sqrt{3} + i)^2}{4}\\
\frac{ i(\sqrt{3} + i)}{2}\\
1
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} \frac{ 2i}{\sqrt{3} - i}\\
\frac{ -2i}{\sqrt{3} + i}\\ 1
 \end{pmatrix}$$
**But still I do not know how this will help me to find a basis for $\mathbb C^3$ so that the given matrix is in triangular form**. I was told that I may find a dual basis, but still I do not know what exactly the steps I should do. Could anyone help me in solving this problem please? (not necessarily using dual basis and probably using an elegant and clean general way of doing this)

Comment: You have three linearly independent eigenvectors. These form a basis relative to which the matrix is diagonal *and therefore triangular*.

Comment: So the eigenvectors form a basis for $\mathbb C^3$? and then I have to diagonalize my matrix? and any diagonalizable matrix is triangular? @BenGrossmann

Comment: 1: Yes, the eigenvectors form a basis. 2: I don't know what you mean by "and then"; by finding the eigenvectors (and noting that they form a basis), you have already "diagonalized" the matrix. 3: Any **diagonal** matrix is triangular. So, if you have "diagonalized" a matrix, then you have also "triangularized" it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My calculations showed the following:

(Kindly try yourself and verify these results)

Eigenvalue: $\lambda_1 = 1$

Eigenvector for $\lambda_1 = 1$:

We solve the equation
$$
(A - \lambda_1 I) \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}
$$

The RREF of $A - \lambda_1 I$ is obtained as
$$
R_1 = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array} \right]
$$

Thus, we solve the equations
$$
x_1 - x_3 = 0, \ \ x_2 - x_3 = 0
$$

Easy to see that we get an eigenvector by taking $x_3$
as a free variable and setting $x_3 = 1$.

Thus, we get the eigenvector
$$\mathbf{v}_1 = \left[ \begin{array}{c}
1 \\
1 \\
1 \\
\end{array} \right] $$

Eigenvalue: $\lambda_2 = -{1 \over 2} - i {\sqrt{3} \over 2} $

Eigenvector for the eigenvalue $\lambda_2$:

We solve the equation
$$
(A - \lambda_2 I) \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}
$$

It is easy to verify that RREF of $A-\lambda_2 I$ is obtained as
$$
R_2 = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & {1 \over 2} + i {\sqrt{3} \over 2} \\[2mm]
0 & 1 & {1 \over 2} - i {\sqrt{3} \over 2} \\[2mm]
0 & 0 & 0 \\[2mm]
\end{array} \right]
$$

Thus, we get an eigenvector as:

$$\mathbf{v}_2 = \left[ \begin{array}{c}
-{1 \over 2} - i {\sqrt{3} \over 2} \\
-{1 \over 2} + i {\sqrt{3} \over 2}  \\
1 \\
\end{array} \right] $$

Eigenvalue: $\lambda_3 = \bar{\lambda}_2 = -{1 \over 2} + i {\sqrt{3} \over 2} $

Eigenvector for $\lambda_3$:

We solve the equation
$$
(A - \lambda_3 I) \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}
$$

It is easy to see that RREF of $A - \lambda_3$ is obtained as
$$
R_3 = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & {1 \over 2} - i {\sqrt{3} \over 2} \\[2mm]
0 & 1 & {1 \over 2} + i {\sqrt{3} \over 2} \\[2mm]
0 & 0 & 0 \\[2mm]
\end{array} \right]
$$

Hence, we get an eigenvector as:
$$\mathbf{v}_3 = \bar{\mathbf{v}}_2 = \left[ \begin{array}{c}
-{1 \over 2} + i {\sqrt{3} \over 2} \\
-{1 \over 2} - i {\sqrt{3} \over 2}  \\
1 \\
\end{array} \right] $$

Form the modal matrix:

$$
P = \left[ \matrix{ 
 \mathbf{v}_1 & \mathbf{v}_2 & \mathbf{v}_3 \cr} \right]
$$

The eigenvectors $\mathbf{v}_1, \mathbf{v}_2, \mathbf{v}_3$ are
linearly independent, since they correspond to different eigenvalues.

It is easy to verify that
$$
P^{-1} A P = D = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
\lambda_1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \lambda_2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \lambda_3 \\
\end{array} \right]
$$

Comment: Do you have the detailed steps of finding the eigenvectors $v_2,v_3$?

Comment: I am unable to reach these values using RREF, if you show these steps, I will appreciate it

Comment: Brain - I added some calculations, but I cannot do step-by-step.. You are expected to do some minimal work!

Comment: Can you please provide the details of finding the RREF of the matrix $A - \lambda_2 I$?

Comment: Brain: I just used elementary row operations. Moderators advised me to give guidelines to OPs, and that you should do some calculations also. Good luck!

Comment: OK, Thank for your help :)